# Xcode 7.0.1 causes issue for iPhone but NOT for iPad?

Tags: ios9, xcode7, device-orientation, facebook-share

I made my app with Objective C and Xcode 6.1. Apple approved it. Updated to Xcode 7.0.1 and now I have errors. The following is code I used in Xcode 6.1. I use UIInterfaceOrientationMask for Orientation so that's not the issue for Xcode 7.0.1

```
-(IBAction)Facebook:(id)sender{    


if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    SLComposeViewController *FACEBOOK = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [self presentViewController:FACEBOOK animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

else{

    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Facebook Account" message:@"Add or create Facebook account in Settings." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
   }
}
```

I flip my device into upside down orientation and click on my Facebook Share button (that I implemented with Social.Framework's SLComposeViewController), the entire app flips by itself into portrait while I'm still holding the phone in upside down orientation. HOW DO I FIX THIS?

When I click out of share message, app goes back to upside down orientation.

The EXACT same code is for iPad but Share Button works on both orientations no problem. But only for Portrait on iPhone. WHAT do I do?